# Iterate through numbers using seq() and rep()

Tags: r

I need to use `rep()` and `seq()` to get the following vector:

```
1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Normally I would just use a `for` statement to achieve this but I am restricted from using that and can only use `rep()` and `seq()` to achieve this vector.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: It's not a homework problem, no. I'm just confused as to how this is possible without having a looping statement that increments.

Comment: Hint: think of constructing `1:5 5-times` and adding the rest (here, checkout the `each` argument to `rep`) appropriately.

Comment: doing
`rep(seq(1, 5), 5)` gives me what you are talking about but I'm just confused as to how I'm supposed to increase using either of those two functions from there on out @Arun

Comment: @turner `rep(seq(5),each=5)+seq(5)-1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
> 1:5 + rep(0:4, each=5)
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: This seems the simplest method to me.

Comment: Although I am supposed to include seq() in the command, this is easily achieved by switching `1:5` to `seq(1, 5)` which completes the parameters equally well, thank you!

Comment: @turner yeah you're right. Just went for the shortest here. Cheers

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer that doesn't use an R loop.

Answer (score 1):

One liner,

```
do.call(c,sapply(1:5,seq,length.out=5,simplify=FALSE))
```

Or even simpler,

```
rep(seq(5),each=5)+seq(5)-1
```

Comment: Wondering if there's a way to do it without addition and subtraction but this serves my purposes, thanks!

Comment: @turner, how the first one-liner? no "+" or "-"; but also no "rep" :)