# Create this vector using rep() and seq()

Tags: r, seq, rep

I'm starting with R language and I have to create this vector using  `rep()` and `seq()`.

```
1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

I've been trying some stuff but but I'm not achieving it.

Comment: literally none of the answers use seq and rep. but that just may be my deja vu talking as [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667405/iterate-through-numbers-using-seq-and-rep) is identical as are the answers. or perhaps I just need some sleep

Comment: @rawr that probably the dupiest dupe I've seen since Im here. This is probably some Coursera like institute giving the same tasks each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
1:5 + rep(0:4,each=5)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 3):

Or like this?

```
c(sapply(1:5, function(x) seq(x,x+4)))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer too I'll be using this one too although we are keeping it very simple for now in our first month in class.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sports of it, adding a `data.table` version using it's `shift` function

```
unlist(data.table(1:10)[, shift(V1, 5:1)][6:10], use.names = FALSE)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: @RichardScriven Good call, forgot about that argument.